# How to use separately deployed .NET assembly in COM application

Tags: c#, com-interop, typelib

I have an application **A** that depends on another application **B**. B is deployed with A unless newer version of B already exists. A is implemented in C++ and C# (using ATL/COM) and B is implemented in C# (COM visible and registered on deploy).

I generate type library (.tlb) from B on built and import it to A's native DLLs. This way we can use B on the native parts of A. This works as expected.

However, I have not found a good way to use B directly in managed sections of A. I thought I could generate interop-assembly from type library but this is not allowed by tlbimp as

> *Type library 'xxx' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.*

This restriction makes absolutely no sense to me. I *could* get around this issue by making a native COM wrapper for B, or by separating all the interfaces of B to another assembly that would be deployed with A (and used for tlb generation) but...come oooon! Is there really no way of generating an interop assembly from managed code?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The interop assembly that is generated by Tlbimp.exe can only be used by managed code.  It objects because it can see that the DLL is already managed code.  In other words, you never need the interop assembly at all since you can use the DLL directly.  Add a reference to it in your A project.

Comment: @HansPassant if I'd be using only small part of B in A, let's call that "B.someFeature.dll", wouldn't I have to deploy all references of that DLL to A's installation folder? At native side, using tlb, "B.someFeature.dll" is loaded from its installation folder where also all its dependencies are. Or do you mean that I only have to build A with "B.someFeature.dll" as it's reference and not to deploy it on A's install folder?